# Change / reverse order of jQuery parents() selector

Tags: jquery

I am using the following selector for an each loop in jQuery:

```
$("#myid").parents().andSelf().each(function({})
```

The selector returns an object like this:

```
object[html, body, div#global_container, div#content, div#myarea, span.myclass, div#myid]
```

That means the `each` loop will start with the furthest parent and then eventually ends with `self`

**How can I reverse that order so that the `each` loop will start with `self` and work its way up the dom tree instead of down?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make `reverse()` work you need to change your jQuery object to an `array` :

```
var elements = $("#myid").parents().andSelf();
elements.toArray().reverse().each(function() {} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6VVAD/

EDIT : The `.each()` function won't work that way because we can't chain it from a non-jQuery object as @scoota269 mentionned

I fixed it by passing the collection into the each function like so :

```
var elements = $("#myid").parents().andSelf();
var reversed_elements = elements.toArray().reverse();

jQuery.each( reversed_elements, function(i, elem) {
     console.log(elem , i)
});
​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reverse` array method.

```
Array.reverse($("#myid").parents().andSelf());
```

Be aware that the `reverse` function is not available on all browsers. But you can use [es5-shim.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js) to fix that.

Comment: `Array.reverse` is available in virtually every browser, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to add a reverse function to jQuery:

`jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse`

The `Array.reverse` is available in virtually all browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Comment: After including the line above in your script, you can 'reverse' the order like so: $('#some_selector').reverse();

Answer (score 0):

`$($("#myid").parents().andSelf().toArray().reverse()).each(function({})`

Comment: There is no in-built `reverse()` function in jQuery. You could build one yourself though.

Comment: Yes but there is a built in one with Javascript. Hence the need to wrap it in a `$()` to use the each. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: That'c correct, but the way you're using it isn't - your code would throw an error. What I mean is there is no `reverse()` method of a jQuery object. You would need to use it in the way that @Magnus has.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Right you are, fixed I believe.

Comment: Why the $ sign before Array.reverse ?

Comment: @jerome.s To convert it back into a jQuery object to allow the .each() function to work.

Comment: `.each()` will work with both arrays and objects http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: @jerome.s Normally I would agree with, however it was throwing type errors without when I was testing.

Comment: @scoota269 yes you are correct I just tested it, that's because we should call each from jQuery object as you said. So we can just pass our collection in our `.each()` : http://jsfiddle.net/6VVAD/1/

Answer (score 0):

I guess `.reverse()` might be pretty expensive for a large node sets, so I would recomment using

`$.merge($el, $el.parents()).each(function(){ ... })`